# Re-direct to " mobile site comming soon" page if webpage is viewed on mobile device

Tags: css, redirect

Im in a situation were our Webpage looks fine on a desktop however if you view it on a mobile device everything gets outa place, i understand this is based on the css i used to create the page, however i am wanting to have a re-direct to a " mobile friendly Site coming soon" page if the website is viewed from a mobile device. Is that at all possible?

Comment: This answer should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/1179865

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries in your css to display your content differently for mobile vs desktop. In your case you could use them to hide and show different content. Or use javascript.